# Beginner: change behaviors for image map hotspots

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm completely new to web design and am just starting out with JS. Although I have found several similar posts online the answers are not detailed enough for me to follow - I need a very basic, step by step tutorial / answer.

I have an image map with several hotspots linked to new pages. I am trying to change behaviors for hotspots triggered by events, for example:

onclick - swap image (different images for different hotspots) OR 
onclick - play sound (again, different sounds for different hotspots).

I have tried:

**JS**

```
function swapImage(filename) {
    document.getElementById("ImgMap1").src="_Images/"+filename;="
}
```

**Html**

```
<area onclick="swapImage('onclick_work_1600x954.png')" id="Work" alt="link 
to work page" coords="378, 65, 599, 195" href="Work.html" shape="rect">
```

I have also tried looking at these two sites, but again my knowledge is too basic to follow the JS:

[David Lynch, Maphighlight](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight)
[ImageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/)

Comment: Are you using plain javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Hi Damon. The above is plain JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function swapImage(filename) {
    document.getElementById("ImgMap1").src="_Images/"+filename;
}
```

***UPDATE***

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3hojqmh/

Just click on the leftmost planet; the function swapImage() is executed and the image source replaced.

***UPDATE 2***

Now check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c3hojqmh/1/

Click on the lady's face and see what happens. Creating images the following way does the trick:

http://www.aws.typo3.hosting-kunde.at/fileadmin/layout/images/bg.jpg

http://www.aws.typo3.hosting-kunde.at/fileadmin/layout/images/ro_media.jpg

Comment: The problem seems to be that this code applies to the img that was inserted as image map, and not to individual hotspots. So what happens is that the image changes once you click anywhere on the img map, instead of different image changes according to the different hotspots...